# How to setup hazel-cast spanning multiple data centers in cloud environment?

Tags: jax-rs, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

How to setup hazlecast embedded in a restful webservice which is deployed on multiple datacenters?

For example:

Datacenter 1:
Node 1 -> hazelcast instance A
Node 2 -> hazelcast instance A

Datacenter 2:
Node 3 -> hazelcast instance A
Node 4 -> hazelcast instance A

Can I achieve something like this in hazelcast?

Comment: What have you tried / researched? And why isn't it ok?

Comment: I have tried deploying with the same setup but somehow the data centers are not communicating. I am trying to perform a lock over a map. Lock isn’t working across data centers for concurrent operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that but you have to ensure there's a stable connectivity between the two data centers, otherwise you may have cluster instabilities (heartbeat timeouts between nodes, long running migrations, etc.) which would degrade your cluster performance significantly. As long as you have a healthy network and you can tolerate the latency there's no problem with such deployment.

One other thing suggested for such deployments is to use [WAN Replication](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/WAN_Replication/Defining_WAN_Replication.html) which is in the Enterprise Edition.

Comment: Thanks. I looked into it. it helped 